# proftpd.conf is empty

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I am on Ubuntu `17.04`, I was trying to configure FTP and accidentally I lost `proftpd.conf` content and it is all empty

path `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` how can I get the default conf content and install FTP on my LINUX box?

Also what is the best editor? is that VI or nano? I am new to non-guid interfaces, this is my first with Linux box. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried to get basic config from here http://www.proftpd.org/docs/configs/basic.conf
But that is not helping, I am not able to restart or remove service. How can I completely reinstall this service?

With the answer from @Redbob I was able to reinstall it then I followed this article to  setup my FTP

http://www.sysadminworld.com/2011/install-proftpd-with-mysql-backend-on-debian-ubuntu/

I get the following error when connecting from FileZilla client

```
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21... 
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... 
Response:   220 ProFTPD
1.3.5b Server (Name-UBUNTU) [10.10.10.6] Command:   AUTH TLS Error: Could not connect to server
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
sudo apt remove --purge proftpd* -y
sudo rm /etc/proftpd/ -rf
sudo apt install --reinstall proftpd
```

I prefer `nano`, but `vi` is also a good editor.

Comment: When I run the first command:
E: Unable to locate package proftpd.conf
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'proftpd.conf'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'proftpd.conf'

Comment: update my question with next blocker, would you be able to help with it?

Comment: Look: https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/10378. Can you access your FTP by some browser? type in address bar:  _ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx/_.  If you could access, may be an filezilla issue.